# Looping parameters within a function

Tags: r, loops

I'm currently conducting research involving the Lokta Volterra Model in R with current code:

```
lotVmod<- function (Time, State, Pars){


 with(as.list(c(State, Pars)),{
    dx= x*(alpha - beta*y)
    dy= y*(gamma - delta*x)
    return(list(c(dx,dy)))
  })
}
Pars<- c(alpha = 1, beta= 1.1, gamma = 0.5,  delta = 1)  
State <- c(x = 0 , y = 0)
Time <- seq(0, 100, by =1)
out<- as.data.frame(ode(func= lotVmod, y= State, parms=Pars, times=Time))

matplot(out[,-1], type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Population")
legend("topleft", c("Aphids", "Parasitoid"), lty = c(1,2), col = c(1,2), box.lwd = 0)
```

I want to to assess the effects of different state ratios on the model outputs. To do this, I guess I need to insert for loops at x and y? however so far I have had no luck working this out despite reading multiple answers and guides. any help will be much appreciated.